# Create a preference for ambiguous overloads

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I'm trying to create my own variant class that can be cast to and from many types. This leads to issues with ambiguous calls for operators like '+' and '-'. Is it possible to create a preference for which casts occur to avoid this?

```
#include <string>

class Variant
{
public:
    Variant() {}
    Variant(int i) : mData(std::to_string(i)) {}
    Variant(double d) : mData(std::to_string(d)) {}

    operator         int() const { return lround(atof(mData.c_str())); }
    operator      double() const { return atof(mData.c_str()); }

private:
    std::string mData;
};


int main() {
    Variant v = 1.2;
    int i = v; //fine
    double d = v; //fine

    double x = v - 1.0; //error, ambiguous, would be nice to prefer a double cast
}
```

Comment: You can overload the operators for `Variant` and "do the right thing" in them.

Comment: *"I'm trying to create my own variant class that can be cast to and from many types."* Implicitly? Doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: This is too vague to be possible to suggest a solution. You need to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the ambiguous overload, that anyone can reproduce themselves, in order to determine the best way to resolve the ambiguity. There are many possible solution. Unfortunately there is no universal solution to solving ambiguous overloads that works for every C++ class in existence, therefore you need to [edit] your question and include [mre], otherwise it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes that's what I was afraid of. That requires defining +(int, Variant), +(Variant, int), -(int, Variant), -(Variant, int), etc. ? Was hoping there was a way to somehow say, 'if the resolution is ambiguous and you can worth with a double, just use that. But that's kind of messy too I guess

Comment: @haporise Fortunately there are templates.  You can define a `template <typename T> auto Variant::operator+(Variant, T)` and `template <typename T> auto Variant::operator+(T, Variant)` so at least you only need to write a pair of functions for each operator.  This is generally what you want to do.  As you've found, too many implicit conversions can make your code not work.  There is no way to tell the compiler how to break a tie on ambiguity.

Comment: You can always mark your constructors and conversion operators as `explicit`, but it sounds like that goes against your plans for this class.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S
{

template <typename T2>
T2 operator-(const T2& i_lhs) const
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<T, T2>);
    auto result = static_cast<T2>(m_member);
    result -= i_lhs;
    return result;
}

T m_member = 20;
};
```

And use it

```
int main()
{
  auto s = S<int>();
  auto s3 = s - 10.0;
  std::cout << s3 << std::endl;
}
```

One more thing, so as to make the behaviour intuitive, provide a number of operators (i.e. Numeric + Variant, Variant + Numeric, and Variant + Variant).

And, the provided code returns a `double`. It may be more intuitive to return a new `Variant`.